# How to create log file in node js getting 502 error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

Could you please tell me How to create a log file using Winston in the root directory?
I am using this package
https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston

Can we create multiple files using after file size increase to 5kb or after 1 hour can we do that?

here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-kapitsa-j1sku

```
const winston = require("winston");
const moment = require("moment");
const path = require("path");
const PROJECT_ROOT = path.join(__dirname, "..");

const consoleLogger = new winston.transports.File({
  timestamp: function() {
    const today = moment();
    return today.format("DD-MM-YYYY h:mm:ssa");
  },
  colorize: true,
  level: "debug"
});

const logger = winston.createLogger();
//   {
//   transports: [consoleLogger]
// }

logger.add(
  new winston.transports.File({
    filename: "test.log",
    maxsize: "10kb"
  })
);

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  logger.transports.console.level = "info";
}
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") {
  logger.transports.console.level = "debug";
}

module.exports.info = function() {
  logger.info.apply(logger, formatLogArguments(arguments));
};
module.exports.log = function() {
  logger.log.apply(logger, formatLogArguments(arguments));
};
module.exports.warn = function() {
  logger.warn.apply(logger, formatLogArguments(arguments));
};
module.exports.debug = function() {
  logger.debug.apply(logger, formatLogArguments(arguments));
};
module.exports.verbose = function() {
  logger.verbose.apply(logger, formatLogArguments(arguments));
};

module.exports.error = function() {
  logger.error.apply(logger, formatLogArguments(arguments));
};

function formatLogArguments(args) {
  args = Array.prototype.slice.call(args);
  const stackInfo = getStackInfo(1);

  if (stackInfo) {
    const calleeStr = `(${stackInfo.relativePath}:${stackInfo.line})`;
    if (typeof args[0] === "string") {
      args[0] = args[0] + " " + calleeStr;
    } else {
      args.unshift(calleeStr);
    }
  }
  return args;
}

function getStackInfo(stackIndex) {
  const stacklist = new Error().stack.split("\n").slice(3);
  // http://code.google.com/p/v8/wiki/JavaScriptStackTraceApi
  // do not remove the regex expresses to outside of this method (due to a BUG in node.js)
  const stackReg = /at\s+(.*)\s+\((.*):(\d*):(\d*)\)/gi;
  const stackReg2 = /at\s+()(.*):(\d*):(\d*)/gi;

  const s = stacklist[stackIndex] || stacklist[0];
  const sp = stackReg.exec(s) || stackReg2.exec(s);

  if (sp && sp.length === 5) {
    return {
      method: sp[1],
      relativePath: path.relative(PROJECT_ROOT, sp[2]),
      line: sp[3],
      pos: sp[4],
      file: path.basename(sp[2]),
      stack: stacklist.join("\n")
    };
  }
}

logger.exitOnError = false;
```

getting error `502`

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the `maxsize` option in `bytes`, so for 5kb it would be:

```
logger.add(
  new winston.transports.File({
    filename: "test.log",
    maxsize: 5 * 1024
  })
);
```

If you want to rotate the log based on time have a look at community mantained packages like [this](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston-daily-rotate-file)

Comment: `cannot log to file without filename or stream`

Comment: Remove `consoleLogger`, there is where you are creating a File transport without `filename`